How can I plot contour lines on a sphere?
Suppose I have an rgl spherical object and I want to plot contours on the surface of this sphere. I figure that the contourLines3d function from the rgl R package is my best bet, so I'm going to adapt their MWE for us here:
lat <- matrix(seq(90, -90, len = 50)*pi/180, 50, 50, byrow = TRUE)
long <- matrix(seq(-180, 180, len = 50)*pi/180, 50, 50)

r <- 6378.1 # radius of Earth in km
x <- r*cos(lat)*cos(long)
y <- r*cos(lat)*sin(long)
z <- r*sin(lat)

open3d()
ids <- persp3d(x, y, z, col = "white",
        specular = "black", axes = FALSE, box = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "",
        normal_x = x, normal_y = y, normal_z = z, polygon_offset = 1)
        
contourLines3d(ids, func)

where I need to specify func properly to plot the contours. This is where I'm struggling. Suppose I have a pdf function (dSphereFunc) that computes the density of any point on the sphere. How can I plot contours using my dSphereFunc? I'm sure there's a relatively simple way to do this, but I'm really having troubles here. Thank you for your help.
Update:
As requested in the comments, I have supplied the density function that I'm trying to evaluate:
dSphereFunc = function(y, mu, Vinv){
    d = length(mu)
    ytVinvy = t(y)%*%Vinv%*%y
    ytmu = t(y)%*%mu
    result = ((2*pi)^(-(d-1)/2))/(ytVinvy^(d/2))*exp((ytmu^2/ytVinvy - t(mu)%*%mu)/2)*mdmo(d, ytmu/(ytVinvy^(1/2)))
    return(result)
}
mdmo = function(d, t){
    t = c(t) # formatting from matrix to constant
    integrand = function(x) x^(d-1)*exp(-(x-t)^2/2)
    integral = integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
    return((2*pi)^(-1/2)*integral$value)
}

In the above function, we are treating mu (a dx1 vector) and V (a dxd matrix) as fixed (i.e., already estimated), where d=3; additionally, y is a dx1 vector which is the spherical coordinates x, y, and z.
To have a MWE, here are some values for mu and Vinv:
mu=c(2,2,2)
Vinv=solve(matrix(c(1.57,-0.08,-0.5,-0.08,0.74,0.34,-0.5,0.34,1.16),nrow=3))
test=c(1,3,4)
test=test/norm(test,type="2")
dSphereFunc(test,mu,Vinv) # 1.156622

I think my trouble is that dSphereFunc takes three arguments, the latter two being fixed. So, I tried using the following function which only requires one argument, xyz which is a dx1 vector for the spherical coordinates x, y, and z:
densFunc = function(xyz){apply(xyz, 1, function(point) dSphereFunc(point, mu, Vinv))}

However, this is still not working.

You should include an example of func.  It's absolutely crucial here, because there are so many ways to define it.  Is it a function of x, y, z, or of lat, long, or some other parameters?

Looking at the ?rgl::contourLines3d, I'd see if I could first plot just latitude as contours, just dropping the reference to longitude in the contourLines3d call to get a sense of things.

@user2554330 Thank you for your comment. I have updated my post to include the function that I'm using. Hopefully, this helps!

@Chris I was able to add the latitude and longitude as contours, but I'm not seeing how I can translate their code into my personal situation. My difficulties seem to concern using my own function (which I have attached in the post).

In words, can you say what ideally your function as plotted would look like as it is not realized as plot yet?

@Chris Sure! The result should be a sequence of ellipses along the surface of the sphere. They should all have the same mean center with varying axes. Image the following graphic, but on the surface of the sphere:
https://i.sstatic.net/Aai9Z.png

The code you were using was fine, the only problem is with the plotting:  the contours all appear on the back of the sphere, so you can't see them.  Setting alpha = 0.5 when you draw the sphere makes them available, or you can rotate the sphere until they show up.  Here the lines are showing through from the back of the sphere:
lat <- matrix(seq(90, -90, len = 50)*pi/180, 50, 50, byrow = TRUE)
long <- matrix(seq(-180, 180, len = 50)*pi/180, 50, 50)

r <- 6378.1 # radius of Earth in km
x <- r*cos(lat)*cos(long)
y <- r*cos(lat)*sin(long)
z <- r*sin(lat)

library(rgl)
open3d()
#> glX 
#>   1
ids <- persp3d(x, y, z, col = "white",
               specular = "black", axes = FALSE, box = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "",
               normal_x = x, normal_y = y, normal_z = z, polygon_offset = 1, alpha = 0.5)

dSphereFunc = function(y, mu, Vinv){
  d = length(mu)
  ytVinvy = t(y)%*%Vinv%*%y
  ytmu = t(y)%*%mu
  result = ((2*pi)^(-(d-1)/2))/(ytVinvy^(d/2))*exp((ytmu^2/ytVinvy - t(mu)%*%mu)/2)*mdmo(d, ytmu/(ytVinvy^(1/2)))
  return(result)
}
mdmo = function(d, t){
  t = c(t) # formatting from matrix to constant
  integrand = function(x) x^(d-1)*exp(-(x-t)^2/2)
  integral = integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
  return((2*pi)^(-1/2)*integral$value)
}

mu=c(2,2,2)
Vinv=solve(matrix(c(1.57,-0.08,-0.5,-0.08,0.74,0.34,-0.5,0.34,1.16),nrow=3))
test=c(1,3,4)
test=test/norm(test,type="2")
dSphereFunc(test,mu,Vinv) 
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 1.156622

densFunc = function(xyz){apply(xyz, 1, function(point) dSphereFunc(point, mu, Vinv))}


contourLines3d(ids, densFunc)


Created on 2024-05-09 with reprex v2.1.0

And what parameter(s) above would one fiddle with to bring the contours 'to the front', initially without rotation of the sphere?

@Chris:  mu gives a direction near the centre of the contours.  So using mu <- c(-2,-2,-2) puts them on the opposite side of the sphere; mu  <- c(0, -2, 0) is quite visible.  mu also controls the amount of spread in them; using smaller values spreads the contours out more.

Thank you, @user2554330. This works very well. I greatly appreciate your patience and time.
